# Redirect subdomain/subfolder to root domain/subfolder - But only in SOME instances

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

When I set up my subdomain, I created some links incorrectly. Now Google thinks I have some pages on both my subdomain and my root domain. I need to fix this, but I can't redirect the entire subdomain.

Examples of what I want to do:

```
https://sub.example.com/ (no redirect)
https://sub.example.com/keep-1 (no redirect)
https://sub.example.com/keep-2 (no redirect)

https://sub.example.com/move-1/* => https://example.com/move-1/*
https://sub.example.com/move-2/* => https://example.com/move-2/*
```

I've tried a number of .htaccess solutions and I'm close, but I can't figure it out. Here's what I've tried:

Attempt #1 - Correctly redirects, but doesn't work as a solution because it redirects everything from the subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Attempt #2 - Doesn't redirect anything - Seems like the right solution but I'm missing something about how redirects work, I think...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com/move-1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/move-1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Attempt #3 - Doesn't redirect anything

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com/move-1/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule https://example.com/move-1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Attempt #4 - Doesn't redirect anything

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sub\.example\.com/move-1/(.*)$ https://example.com/move-1/$1 [R=301]
```

My .htaccess file is in the root domain's root html folder and seems to have control. I have also tried these from the subdomain's root folder, but that didn't redirect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^move(.*) https://example.com/move$1 [R=301,L]
```

`%{HTTP_HOST}` is the host name, mapped to domain such as `sub.example.com` or `example.com`. It does not contain any `path` part, that follows behind the domain. `$1` is back-reference, mapped to the regex part `(.*)`. The `RewriteRule` tells if the request uri pattern starts with `/move`, then redirect to `https://example.com/move$1` permanently.